# Insert row at bottom for kendo UI Grid angular 2+

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular8, kendo-ui-angular2

Instead of adding the new row in the top of each grid for kendo UI grid, I want to add it in the bottom, but I have no idea how to do it and where do i need to change the code. I am using the existing add row function for kendo UI grid for angular 8.  Calling the addR function in HTML

```
(add)="addR($event,grid)"
```

addR function in typeScript

```
 addR(event, gird, service ){
    this.saveEditableR(event.action, service, grid).pipe(first()).subscribe(rowSaved => {
        if (rowSaved) {
          this.getGridForm(grid);
          service.senderRef = event.sender;
          service.rowIndex = -1;
          service.isNewItem = true;
          event.sender.addRow(service.form);
        } else {
          this.displayGridError(grid);
        }
      });
  }

saveEditableR(action, service: any, grid, saved: boolean): Observable<boolean> {
    
    let form = service.form;
    let sender = service.sender;
    let rowIndex = service.rowCount-1;
    let isNew = service.isNew;
    let rowSaved;
    if(form){
      if(form.valid && action !='editEmit'){
        const Grid: any = form.value;
        if(!this.validateGridData(Grid, rowIndex, grid)){
          sender.save.emit({sender, Form, rowIndex, isNew});
          sender.closeRow();
          rowSaved =true;
          if(action === 'edit' && isNew){
            this.serive.updateRowIndex = true;
          }
        }else{
          if(save){
            console.log("ERROR OCCUR");
          }
          rowSaved = false;
        }
      }else {
        if(saved){
          console.log("ERROR OCCUR");
        }
        rowSaved = false;
      }
    }else{
      rowSaved = true;
    }
    return of(rowSaved);
  }
```

Comment: Try using the `sort` functionality to sort by the row's `id` or `created_date`. Those can be calulated by you when creating the row and then just sort by it using the built in `sort` functionality of the `kendo-grid`